# Объясните выхлоп асма: откуда $8583909746840200520 при создании "Hello, world!\n"

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Не могу понять ассемблерный код, получаемый в результате компиляции простейшей программы:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char str[] = "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

При использовании *gcc6.3 x86_64* получается такой результат:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movabsq $8583909746840200520, %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $1684828783, -8(%rbp)
    movw    $2593, -4(%rbp)
    movb    $0, -2(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Откуда берётся `$8583909746840200520`?

Замечу, что если написать так:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char str[] = "Hello, world!\0";
}
```

то получается совсем другое:

```
.LC0:
    .string "Hello, world!"
    .string ""
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movl    .LC0+8(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movzwl  .LC0+12(%rip), %eax
    movw    %ax, -4(%rbp)
    movzbl  .LC0+14(%rip), %eax
    movb    %al, -2(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: А что смущает во втором случае? Компилятор волен сам выбирать как ему инициализировать переменные.

Comment: @PinkTux, да не пойму в чем принципиальная разница окончания строки на \0 или на \n с точки зрения компилятора

Comment: Возможно (только гипотеза), что явный 0 внутри кавычек заставляет воспринимать данные не как "сишную строку", а именно как массив, отсюда и разные методы. Но нужно ещё понимать с какой оптимизацией всё это компилируется.

Comment: В первом случае `str` формально является строкой. Во втором - формально  не является.  Понятно, что это отличие - не повод для разницы в таком "ничего не делающем" коде, но тем не менее. Да и есть подозрение, что код компилировался без оптимизаций, что делает вопрос о разнице бессмысленным.

Comment: @Ant, ну да, без оптимизаций... осваиваю вот асм... разумеется без оптимизаций, иначе вообще черт ногу сломит, ничего не понятно становится

Comment: оффтоп:  этот код содержит иллюстрацию соответствия стандарту С99: movl    $0, %eax - возврат 0 даже если  main() не содержала return

Answer (score 17, accepted):

8583909746840200520(dec) == 77202C6F6C6C6548(hex) == "w ,olleH"(str), второе гигантское число - остаток строки.

Comment: чет не могу въехать как вы так переконвертировали строку в число

Comment: @xperious Hiew - выделить - Shift-F8-hex2bin, но у вас этого нет, поэтому http://www.asciitable.com/ и смотрите: 0x77 - 'w' и так далее...

Comment: @Abyx: проще: `8583909746840200520 .to_bytes(8, 'little')`. [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)

Comment: я не могу понять по какому алгоритму эта конвертация работает

Comment: Это что такое??

Comment: @xperious, вы знакомы с понятием "ascii-код символа"?

Comment: @jfs кандидат на ассоциацию!

Comment: @Nofate, ну как оказалось, там не тупо подряд шли hex-значения каждого символа, а лишь двоичное представление, что в hex уже совсем другое значение... разобрался короче

Comment: @xperious как же это не тупо hex? 0x77 - 'w', дальше 0x20 - пробел. То есть тупо и hex

Comment: @xperious так как  платформа у вас little-endian, то байты в числе у вас идут от младшего к старшему. Но каждвый байт это и есть двоичное представление символа, aka hex, aka ASCII code, в данном случае. С  widechar или Unicode будет веселее, там  шестнадцатеричные значения (идентификаторы) символов НЕ совпадают с двоичным представлением.

Comment: 77202C6F6C6C6548(hex) = "Hello, w" в  памяти little endian, в памяти порядок байт иной чем в записи.

Comment: @Swift, ну да, я уж допер, спасибо